# VC++, using AfxBeginThread in OnTimer

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to use AfxBeginThread in OnTimer, like this:

```
void CFrame::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{
  if(nIDEvent==definedid)
    funA();
    //funB();
}

bool CFrame::funA()
{
   m_pThreadExecute = AfxBeginThread(threadFun, &threadPar, ThreadPry);
}

bool CFrame::funB()
{
   //do something without thread
}

int threadFun(LPVOID lpVoid)
{ 
  //do something
}
```

I set timer 1 second, if I call funB(), do something without thread, this timer run one time per second, normally; if I call funA(), this timer just run once, how can I use AfxBeginThread in OnTimer?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AfxBeginThread, huh?
It seems that you use MFC [CWnd::SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49313fdf.aspx) but it is just a wrapper over Win32 API [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can try to do the same with Win32 API SetTimer and try passing NULL instead of window handle. Providing NULL window handle causes the timer to be replaced if you call such SetTimer call once again, though. An [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_timer).

And/or you probably better just use Win32 API [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that should not disturb other things.

On the other hand, what you do appears to be a bit strange. Is there a need to start new thread all the time? If not, we can probably figure out an alternative. Starting threads, especially too many threads, without real need is usually a way to produce unnecessary bugs and complications.